# Custom Post Type post not appearing

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I am new to WordPress. My problem is that I created a custom post type named `Atividades` and when I create a post, it does not appear on the website.

```
// fuctions.php
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' ); function create_post_type()
{ register_post_type( 'acme_atividade',         array(          'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Atividades' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Atividade' )            ),      'public' => true,       'has_archive' => true,      )   ); }

// index.php
<div id="atividades">
                    <div id="col1">
                        <div style="background: url('<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>') no-repeat;" id="q-1">

                <?php
                $thumbnail = '';
                if (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail')) {
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'thumbnail');
                }
                }
                ?>

                <?php 
                query_posts(array( 
                'post_type' => 'Atividades',
                'posts_per_page' => 1 
                ) );  
                ?>

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } ?>

                <h1 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>

                <?php the_content(); ?>

                <?php endwhile; else: ?>

                <h1 class="title">Ups...</h1>

                <p>... pedimos desculpa mas nenhum <em>post</em> foi encontrado!</p>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <p align="center"><?php posts_nav_link(); ?></p>

            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: As this is no chat and questions & answers serve as source for later readers, please care about your MarkUp and use upper-, lowercase letters. Please go back and edit your question, so your MarkUp is readable. Hint: There's a WYSIWG editor to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.php` the `query_post` should be :

```
 query_posts(array( 
     'post_type' => 'acme_atividade',
     'posts_per_page' => 1 
  ) );
```

You should use the name of the post type `acme_atividade` instead of the post type's label.

Comment: not working yet :(

Comment: Please explain **why** that could solve the problem.